# Grails : how to access data in javascript from controller

Tags: grails

I have some data in My controller which i want to use in Javascript in my gsp file

```
class MainController {
    def test = {

        def value = 111.10
    }
}
```

TEST.GSP

```
<html>
    <head><title>Simple GSP page</title></head>
    <body>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            alert("${value}")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Dialog box appears but without any value .. Any Solution ..?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explain grails, that he local variable `value` should be accessible in the view, by returning a map of all variables, that should be accessible in the view:

```
class MainController {
    def test = {

        def value = 111.10
        [value: value]
    } 
}
```

Comment: it should be working, maybe you are in the wrong controller method. is your gsp name seriously upper case? double check, whether action name and view name is the same.